# Aggregate feed, removing duplicates in getstream

Tags: getstream-io

I have followed the adivce here [stackoverflow aggregate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923427/how-to-build-a-news-feed-with-aggregate-and-flat-types)

I am grouping posts together
(shares for same post together, likes for same posts together, regular posts as single activities).  What I'm noticing, however, is that I end up with duplicates for a user. 
If a user shares a post, and also likes the post, it shows up twice on their getstream feed.
Right now, I have to do filtering on my own backend service with a certain order
(If you share a post, remove the activity if you also liked it).
If you like a post, then remove the regular post.
Is there a better way to solve this problem of duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

One idea that comes to mind: when you post an activity of a share, make sure you send a `foreign_id` and `time` (sending both will avoid duplicates in our system), then if you also 'like' the activity you could store a `like` counter in the activity metadata, and send an update with the foreign_id and incrementing the `like` count.

Keep in mind that updates don't push to aggregated feeds or notification feeds, though, so you'd still want to push that 'like' activity to those feeds, too.