# GetStream: Prevent adding the same activity in flat-feed

Tags: getstream-io

I'm using a flat-feed, to be able to follow and unfollow other profiles.
But as i see it, i want to group the verbs as it is possible in the aggregated-feed.

Because i want to aggregate likes to the same activity.

**user2** and **user3**, likes **image1**.

**user1** follow **user2** and **user3**.

Meaning that **user1** now have two activities, of users liking the same image and i want it to be displayed as one activity.

Should i handle this myself by sorting it with the foreign key and then collect the activities into one? Or can i somehow blend the flat-feed with aggregated-feed?

This [How to build a news feed with aggregate and flat types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923427/how-to-build-a-news-feed-with-aggregate-and-flat-types) is similar, but i need to be able to follow and unfollow.

Comment: can you elaborate why using an aggregated feed would not work in your case?

Comment: As i understand, i can't follow an aggregated feed. And i'm going to build a personalised-feed for each profile, based on the followed profiles.

Comment: aggregation is done by feeds that follows other feeds. in most cases you add activities to flat feeds (eg. profile/home feed) and follow them to get timelines or aggregated timelines

Comment: So to understand it correct: I would have to build different feeds(flat(like profile/home as you said)), that i then follow with a profile feed(aggregated)?

Comment: there are a few tutorials from the doc pages you can use to get a better idea: https://getstream.io/docs/#social-network

Comment: The possibility of combining aggregated and flat feeds did the trick for me. I didn't realised that it was possible. Thanks Tommaso Barbugli.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could reply to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out that i could combine flat-feed and aggregated-feed i came up with this setup:

In this example beneath, **User2** is publishing an artwork, meaning that *User2-feed* now includes an activity that shows his artworks.
Shortly after **User3** likes his newly posted artwork, meaning that *User3-feed* now include an activity that shows his like of the artwork.
**User1** is following *User2-feed* and *User3-feed* which create *User1-aggregatedfeed* that include all activities from the two feeds, that **User1** is currently following. It means that **User1**’s own activity will not being shown in his own *User1-aggregatedfeed* unless he is following his own feed, which isn’t possible.
The same artwork that is added to *User2-feed* is also added to *Artist1-feed* because the artist of the artwork is **Artist1**. Meaning that the same artwork is now added to two feeds that **User1** is following. But activity will only be added to *User1-aggregatedfeed* once, because we store the “artwork publish” activity with the same foreign key.

[Flat-feed combined with aggregated-feed example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrhzw.png)